# Using roslaunch with gdb gives error 'tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device'

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to debug my node with gdb but I consistently get two errors, and I don't know if they are related.

First of all, I added `launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args"` to my node as instructed in [the tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

Now, when I launch my node, I get this error about 30 times during the initialization phase: `tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Also, when I try to close the node, it stops a few threads but seems to hang and not stop the other threads. I do not normally have threading problems.

Are these problems related? I know that the error that I got was reported with Gazebo in the past, but here it has nothing to do with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48056/using-roslaunch-with-gdb-gives-error-%27tcsetpgrp-failed-in-terminal_inferior:-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device%27/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
I'm not quite sure why you are getting the tcsetpgrp errors but maybe the terminal roslaunch provides does not support all features gdb wants.

**Comment by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on 2013-01-21**:
I used this option: `launch-prefix="gdb --args"`

to launch gdb in my terminal however I got the same error:

```
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
```

each time I hit or continue from a break point.

**Comment by [bot777](https://answers.ros.org/users/53664/bot777/) on 2021-09-19**:
Hello All,

I have the same problem... launch file is below (followed as above and changed the launch_prefix):

```
<launch>

<arg name="debug" default="false"/> <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value=""/> <arg if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="xterm -e gdb --args"/>

<arg name="config" default="false"/> <arg unless="$(arg config)" name="command_args" value=""/> <arg if="$(arg config)" name="command_args" value="-d $(find inmoov6_moveit_config)/launch/moveit.rviz"/>

<node name="$(anon rviz)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" args="$(arg command_args)" output="screen"> <rosparam command="load" file="$(find inmoov6_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/> </node>

</launch>
```

but I still get the same error message: tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Please advice on what I need to do specifically? to resolve it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/223

---

Originally posted by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) with karma: 132 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Faced same thing. But I just did `launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"` instead of `launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args"`.  The former opens gdb in a different xterm window, and you can type in "run". That worked for me

---

Originally posted by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) with karma: 71 on 2015-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-01-30**:
Thank you! This works.